# how to increase the quota for Google Sheets API

Tags: google-sheets-api

we have an online service for integrating different services and applications with each other. We don't have enough limits. The requests are written optimally, we do not make unnecessary requests.

Comment: hi, your question is too general. 
try to write  more specific and detailed question. 
you can try this schema : 
- what are you currently doing
- what do you want to achieve
- what is the obstacle (error, e.g.)
- what already you try to solve (but still not working).
also if you have code example or diagram to make other understand your question better,  it would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can request for a quota increase through your GCP Console. Just follow the steps below:

1.) Login to your GCP Console admin account.

2.) On the navigation menu, click on IAM & Admin -> Quotas.

3.) Select the API service that you will request for an increase. Tick the checkbox on the right side of the console then click EDIT QUOTAS in the top part of the screen.

4.) Specify the new quota limit that you want and you are done with the request.

Quota increase requests usually take 2-3 days.

### Reference

[Increasing API Quota](https://support.google.com/supportu/answer/2700653?hl=en)

Comment: Would be nice if it would work this way, but the default quota limit is 300 write and 300 read requests per minute, which is also the maximum that can be requested with this method.
Other API's have a link to "apply for higher quota", Google Sheets API doesn't have this link in the "Edit Quotas" form.